# CSS doesn't toggle

Tags: jquery

The following successfully toggles the div landlord_pop_up. However, it doesn't set the css property for the div landlord_pop_up on toggle. Any ideas would be much appreciated. I am try to get the popupBox height to change from 20em to 42 em on toggle.

```
$(function () {
    $('#toggle1').click(function () {
        $('#landlord_pop_up').slideToggle(function () {
            $(".popupBox").css({
                "height": "42em"
            });
        }, function () {
            $(".popupBox").css({
                "height": "20em"
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This toggles the height of the pop up box after sliding:

```
$(function() {
    $('#toggle1').click(function() {
        $('#landlord_pop_up').slideToggle(function(){
            $(".popupBox").toggle(function () {
                $(this).height("42em");
            }, function () {
                $(this).height("20em");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: yeah, it was ok before, but i just posted this answer as alternative to yours because the question was unclear to me... thats the biggest frustration actually...

Comment: @Vishal i was actually about to vote for you're original answer as it seems a correct answer to this question, as does mine. `on toggle` is that before or after? or maybe we really need to wait with a `setTimeout`...

Answer (score 0):

according to [docs](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)
slideToggle takes `duration` as first argument. and you are providing a function

```
.slideToggle(duration,callback);
```

so you can do something like this

```
$('#landlord_pop_up').slideToggle(1000, 
function () { 
 $(".popupBox").css({"height":"20em"});
 $(".popupBox").css({"height":"42em"});
});
```

Comment: so you're changing height to both 20em and 42 em at same time?